# Facebook App Linking from pages not working anymore

Tags: facebook, deep-linking, facebook-page, facebook-call-to-action

It's been about 2 months now. We manage several facebook pages and all these pages were linking to native iOS / Android apps from the CTA button where users were either opening their apps via "Use App" link or were redirected to download them in case they didn't have it installed.

What happens now is that the dialog to connect your app via the "add button" function in Facebook pages, it only shows a textfield to redirect the users to a website (image attached). There is no way to link to a registered app (of course there is a related app registered with all the relevant platforms enabled and the admin has access to it). Facebook, as always is completely silent and not responding to any support requests, clients that had their apps linked to pages now ask us what happened and we are out in the cold without being able to understand wtf is happening.

This happens to 90% of our pages, some of them still have a "Use App" button that works just fine, but all others have the above problem. Also, new pages, suffer from the same problem as well. Changing the page theme doesn't seem to do anything. One (strange) finding is that if you download the pages management app in a mobile device, there is also a checkbox which allows to enter a deep link url besides the standard url but just that. The list with the apps that we had access to link to pages has just vanished.

Any ideas? Anyone having the same issue?

[image: the list of available (admin) apps has vanished and there is only a textfield now for a website url]

Comment: I made some progresss by following this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api and creating an applink to use for the url field. But, still even though the link works perfectly on all devices, on the call to action buttons it always opens the appstore or the website instead of the app. Any thoughts?